# How to avoid/prevent infinite recursive call in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, recursion

I have a javascript function in my `Node.js` application which calls itself to find its level in parent-child hierarchy in MongoDB. A document will try to find its parent and if found will increase the level and goes on till there is no parent found. It looks like the following,

```
function findLevel(doc, level, callback){
    if(!doc)
        return callback(null, level);
    var query = {
        id: doc.parentID
    };
    model.findOne(query, function(err, parentDoc){
        if(err){
            return callback(err, level)
        };
        return findLevel(parentDoc, level+1, callback);
    })
}
```

This has high chance of producing infinite recursive calls. One of the scenario is parentID is same as the current doc's id. That can be avoided by including another condition in find query, but still I am worried about I may miss something and it can cause the entire application to crash/kill. Is there a recommended way to avoid/prevent this kind of situation in `Node.js`? Or can we restrict the level of recursive calls and stop it gracefully like saying the recursive call should go only till this `n` level?

Comment: when the returned parent doc id is same as query id, thats the point where you stop, right ?

Comment: and if you really care about just the top level parent, why not while saving the doc, save it with top level parent's id. Or run a batch job at some time to do path compression.

Comment: @Sikorski No. In a perfect scenario, we stop when no parent found.

Comment: @Sikorski Currently I can't change the structure of the document. I am looking for a solution with the existing one.

Comment: so will it happen that a doc will refer to itself as parent ? or perhaps how will it happen !

Comment: Yes, infinite recursion happens when the doc refers itself as the parent. That is one possible scenario. I don't find any other now. Still, I want to be cautious

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136431/discussion-between-sikorski-and-rar).

Comment: Every recursive algorithm should have a recursion termination condition.

Comment: Why do you think this would crash your application?

Comment: @Bergi I thought the infinite recursion will cause `"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"` error and that would crash the application.

Comment: @RaR No, the "recursive" call happens in an asynchronous callback which has its own stack. Node would handle infinite recursion quite well (though constantly stressing the db connection might make it unresponsive)

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. So, the application won't crash because of infinite recursion since the recursive call is inside async callback. That's great. But still, infinite recursion is not a good thing, is it? If my API call depends on the result of this function, it won't get any response ever, right? Is there a way to handle this in Node. Or is it completely in our hand, making sure this kind of situation never come?

Comment: Of course, yes, that one request will hang :-) (and getting many of these will eventually exhaust resources). Putting a bound on `level` or keeping a history of visited graph nodes is definitely a good idea. Or not constructing circular graphs in the first place.

Comment: Okay got it @Bergi. Thank you once again for the clarification. I will go for putting a bound on `level` :-)

Comment: Another way would be to collect all IDs you've seen and stop with an error, as soon as your recursion takes you to an ID you've seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement cycle detection by making note of all the IDs you encounter during recursion and stopping as soon as an ID has been handled before.

```
function findLevel(doc, callback) {
    var level = 0, seen = {};

    (function getParent(doc) {
        // proper termination
        if(!doc || !doc.parentID) return callback(null, level);

        // cycle detection
        if (seen.hasOwnProperty(doc.parentID)) return callback(new Error("cycle detected"));
        seen[doc.parentID] = true;

        // recursion
        model.findOne({id: doc.parentID}, function (err, parentDoc) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            level++;
            getParent(parentDoc);
        });
    })(doc);
}
```